# How to access JSON array of objects, returned by PHP PDO, inside javascript/jQuery?

Tags: jquery, json, pdo

I have a largely PHP-based web app. that also uses - on one or two pages - JQuery and JQWidgets - both of which I am new to. For data access, I have a data-layer.php file containing all my PDO requests to the MySQL database. These all work perfectly with PHP.

In my data-layer.php file, at the end of this PDO SELECT function: 
**getMembersAtActivity($PDOdbObject, $eventId, $actId)**, I have added a "json_encode($rows)" statement to translate my returned rows to JSON format, as required by JQWidgets.

All this works well. Now in my PHP/HTML page, I want to construct the nice JQWidget that uses this JSON-formatted data.

In PHP I can do a print_r to see that there is indeed an array (unnamed) of objects, returned by the getMembersAtActivity function. However, I don't know how to make a variable that contains this array in JQuery, which is necessary to populate a JQListbox with my JSON rows.

There are many, many posts here that show how to iterate through a JSON array, but this is not my problem. I first need to grab a reference to that array of objects, which is in a different PHP data file, and then iterate through the array so that I can build a list box with JQWidgets.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1):

If it's in a separate PHP file then AJAX seems like the best choice. Take a look at the documentation for the [`jQuery.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) wrapper function. Basic usage would look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // on page load
    $.getJSON('yourpage.php', function(data) {
        // data is your array
        // use it to create your widget in here
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks very much! i was hoping to find my way thru the JSON and PDO issues before I tackle Ajax, because i'm struggling with new stuff as it is. i got hold of the JQWidgets support team too so i'm hopeful of getting the answer soon.